# "pip install" installed packages for all version of python on my MacOS

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pip

Using macOS Catalina(10.15.5). I installed Python3.8 from python.org along with pip3.
Somehow my pip3 and pip now point to the same pyhton3.8.

```
pip -V 
pip 20.1.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

pip3 -V
pip 20.1.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

So I thought if I do `pip install numpy`, or `pip3 install numpy`, numpy would be installed for python3.8.

However, when I tried to import numpy using python2.7(pre-built into macOS), it showed that numpy is there somehow. But I think I only installed pip for python3.8, so how come python2.7 also gets installed numpy.

```
python -V
Python 2.7.16
>>> import numpy
>>> print(numpy)
<module 'numpy' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.pyc'>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you feel like keeping better control of your environment in general I recommend using venv (`python3 -m venv <folder>` or something similar).  I know it's a little annoying at first, but I've grown to like them.

Comment: `numpy` is preinstalled for the system Python 2.7 and is part of MacOS. It is somewhat old though, version 1.8 or so.

Comment: Was there previously. Maybe as a dependancy.